# Xdebug on XAMPP and Notepad++ won't connect

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I have a really slow script from someone else that I need to profile to speed up, I have followed numerous tutorials however it keeps leading to the same step.

I have downloaded the appropriate binary from xDebug's site, by copying the phpinfo [into  Xdebug's website find_binary.php search functionality](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php).

I have a seemingly correct setup.

Notepad++ (NPP) is configured to connect to Xdebug via 127.0.0.1:9000 with the specified IDE key.

The following is the section of php.ini specific to xdebug.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I am using PHP 5.4.4.

My phpinfo output does not mention Xdebug.

Comment: You can use netbeans instead of notepad++

Comment: Check in command prompt if `php -i` or `php -v` return warnings about configuration, modules or libraries.

Comment: mrowa, php -i returns this: PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 21:27:06) - Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group - Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies - php -v displays a limited section of phpinfo(). No errors were found, however.

Comment: Can you tell the original name of php_xdebug.dll (what you really need is: compiler version, eg. "vc9")?
Than, search phpinfo() result for "Compilator" and see if the dll has the same compiler version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For **windows with php5.3 and up** you need to use `zend_extension` instead of `zend_extension_ts` in your php.ini file.

Example

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

If you use the xdebug wizard http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and you get this message
**Xdebug is only loaded as PHP extension and not as a Zend Extension**
It is because of using zend_extension_ts (I think).

**Another thing to note.**

You won't see anything in notepad if you don't set breakpoints in the code you are testing. It will run so fast that it will seem like it is not working (if you watch carefully though, notepad plus will flash). Took me a long time to realize that.

**Thirdly**

I would recommend downloading the latest xdebug.dll for your system
available from http://xdebug.org/download.php

**xdebug has only been compatible with php 5.4 since** [2012-05-08] - Xdebug 2.2.0
The latest version is Xdebug 2.2.1

I'd also recommend using the latest version of DBDG plugin (notepad plus requires this file to work with Xdebug) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DBGP%20Plugin/

**ANOTHER THING**

**EDIT:** Just noticed your using XAMPSERVER,but I'll leave it in case it is useful for someone else. If you are using wampserver 2.2, xdebug is preinstalled. This might be causing problems if you manually installed xdebug again later and manage to have 2 versions installed or something crazy like that.

**My last working php.ini file for xdebug**

Please note my last version was working, albeit very slowly. In the php.ini I have the ide set to xdebug, but I could call it any session name I wanted and it worked. You probably don't need all of the info I've posted below and you will most likely need to change the file path and file name. I was using D drive.

```
[xdebug]

;for windows with php5.3 and up you need to use zend_extension instead of zend_extension_ts
zend_extension="D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=On
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```

[image]

**LASTLY**

Don't forget to use `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sessionname` at the end of the url address of the code you wish to test.

EXAMPLE

```
http://localhost/codetotest.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=xdebug
```

Also restart your server's services after making any changes else they won't take effect.

Comment: moomoochoo, Chaning to zend_extension from zend_extension_ts worked perfectly. Many thanks - I am surprised the solution was so simple! I was since able to figure out the issue without XDebug (sloppy coding from the last guy), however now that xDebug is working, it will be helpful for future use. Many thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the hardest to find :P Glad you got it sorted:)

Comment: They definately are. Thanks for your assistance. Voted up and correct answer.

Comment: I have searched all over the internet literally for *years* for this solution. I wish I could upvote this one thousand times

Answer (score 0):

For windows 8,  recent xamp php 5.5 make sure u have VC11 , and  xdebug dll:  php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.5-vc11.dll, and insert the above php.ini fixes, with the replacement of d: dir with c: path to your xamp. It appears critical to replace localhost with 127... .